# Why is my rails app showing a blank page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am going though Michael Hartl's rails Tutorial chapter 10 section 10.2. And my rails app is now showing a blank page for all pages I try to load on the local host.  I have tried resetting the computer as suggested in another post, but this didn't work. I have checked the development log and here is the error message.

```
Started GET "/users/3" for 95.10.6.124 at 2017-11-05 16:36:43 +0000
Cannot render console from 95.10.6.124! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (27.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.5ms)
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 41ms (Views: 38.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

This is strange as I undid the changes I made and now it doesnt work. In fact the serve doesnt seem to start. Instead of seeing the usual "ctrl+c to stop" at the end, the command prompt appears. This hasnt happened before and to my mnowledge I havent done anything differently.

Could someone help me with this, thanks.

Comment: Are you using Vagrant, Docker by any chance?

Comment: what is Vagrant Docker?

Comment: So, try whitelisting the ip, add `config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '95.10.6.124'` to your config/environments/development.rb file.

Comment: Are you using  Cloud 9?  I see  the `Cannot render console` all the time on Cloud 9 and it does not affect the main page.  What do you see when you type `rails s` or `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT` (Cloud 9)?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma. Palma, thanks that seemed to work. I wonder if you or someone else could briefly explain what the problem was and why that worked. And also why that problem suddenly occurred. because i have been using this command to start the server with no problem up until now. understanding it would help me in the future for any errors. thanks